Phase noise compensation in carrier tracking loops at 38 GHz
I am trying to reach an estimate for a number in dBs of phase noise improvement in a Costas tracking loop. I know that there is a trade off there as increasing the loop BW helps reducing the input phase noise but in the same time causes the loop to ad more of its own noise due to a larger loop BW. Is there a kind of a typical approximate number in dBs what one could reasonably expect?
So suppose my input integrated  phase noise is around -15 dBc at 38 GHz (which is not a good performance), what improvement can one reasonaly expect: -18 dBc, -20 dBc?

I don't have the experience in data communications to tell you if there's a typical value.  But if you can reduce your Costas loop to a control system-style block diagram, you can compute the phase noise rejection for that loop.

You can't only use integrated phase noise for estimate..as you said, it relates to BW. But phase noise is frequency dependent and changing BW also changes integration. The shape of your phase noise curve is important. If phase noise is very low close-in and quite high further out of the carrier the filtering will result in different integrated value compared to higher close-in and lower further out curve with the same filtering.
